# $\log_{10}(1+10^{-n})<10^{-n}$?

Tags: logarithms

In a paper I was reading, this inequality:
$$\log_{10}(1+10^{-n})<10^{-n}$$
came up with no explanation for why it's true. Does anyone have a proof for why this holds? Is there some basic logarithm property I'm missing?

Comment: My bad - it's the first one, 10^-n.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because:

- $\ln(1+x)\leqslant x$ for every $x\gt-1$
- $\log_{10}(t)=\ln(t)/\ln(10)$ by definition
- $\ln(10)\gt1$ since $10\gt\mathrm e$

Hence, $\log_{10}(1+10^{-n})=\ln(1+10^{-n})/\ln(10)\lt10^{-n}/\ln(10)\lt10^{-n}$.

Comment: Would you really say that $\log_{10} t = \dfrac{\log_e t}{\log_e 10}$ is a DEFINITION? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes. Wouldn't you?

Comment: No.  Mathematical logic hasn't caught up with practice here.  "Rigor" may be characterized as either writing proof amenable to having their soundness checked algorithmically, or convincing oneself in each instance that one knows how to write such a proof.  I think a characterization like that is treated as a definition _only_ as a means to fit everything into that kind of concept of rigor. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry but you lost me.

Answer (score 1):

For every number $x>-1$ 
$$
\log_e(1+x)\le x.
$$

Therefore
$$
\log_{10}(1+\varepsilon) = \frac{\log_e(1+\varepsilon)}{\log_e 10} \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\log_e 10}
$$

And $\log_e 10>2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=1+x-10^x$, note that if $x>0$, then $f'(x)<0$, then $f$ is decreasing, how $f(0)=0$, then $f(x)<0$:
$$1+x-10^x<0\implies 1+x<10^x\implies \log_{10}(1+x)<x$$